# How can I filter out noise from irrelevant stack exchange sites in my feed on the mobile app?

Tags: support, android-app, android-app-feed

I am not interested in Harry Potter or role playing games, but my feed seems to be full of those things. Is there a way to turn them off, or just pick the sites that I'm interested in?

Comment: You can't. There's already a feature request asking to add such ability.

Comment: I don't believe this question was closed correctly. Firstly, it says there is another question that has already been answered - while the linked question has zero answers. Secondly, it's a different question - the linked question wants to remove content from SE sites that he has participated in, while I want to remove content from sites that I have never participated in.

Comment: No point reopening as the only answer is "No, it's not possible". And the feature request is the same: have control over what sites you see in the feed.

Comment: @PeterHall Meta SE is special in duplicate system since it'd be very troublesome without it to close duplicate feature requests, bugs, etc, and this question is also correctly closed per above comment.